# I want to be notified when a LAN IP goes live

Tags: monitoring, ip, ping, network-monitoring

Is there a tool or something that can notify me whenever a local IP goes live on my network.

It could be that it continually ping that IP and display a notification to me whenever that IP return a packet.

I'm a programmer myself and I can write such a tool myself without a problem, but if there exist such a tool already that would be great (even if it is a command line tool)

Best Regards,

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 2):

If your network uses DHCP you may try [arpwatch](http://ee.lbl.gov/) and filter for the specific MAC address of the host you're looking for.

Comment: Arpwatch can be setup to automatically send an email when a new ip/mac address is seen on the network. As it's name suggests, it monitors arp requests so it should work in non-DHCP environments also.

Answer (score 0):

[Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/index.en.html) probably does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Zabbix! It's a tool that has many features including host ping and network discovery